# authorizet.net local testing and ssl certificate

Tags: php, authorize.net

hi i am integrating authorize.net AIM api into my shopping cart. i have a developer account from auth.net and i am working locally. when i do auth.net api call, i get

**SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed**

i assume it's because i dont have ssl on my local machine. how do i get over this so i can test on my local machine? thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't specify how you are connecting to Authorize's API, but I'm assuming you are probably using cURL. You need to turn off certificate verification:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);